# Create portable android development environment

Tags: android, eclipse, portability, android-virtual-device

I would like to have a portable android development environment that I could take everywhere (e.g. a usb stick). The idea is to have a folder that would include:

- eclipse
- android-sdk
- jdk
- .android (folder that contains the avd's and keys)
- workspace

I installed Eclipse 3.7.0, added ADT plugin and

- added option "-vm ../jdk/bin/" in eclipse.ini file
- set the eclipse android-sdk variable to a relative path (../android-sdk)
- set the eclipse workspace to a relative path
- set the eclipse key folder to a relative path

The question is how can you make the avd's portable? How can .android folder be portable? I saw some solutions mentioning the creation of an environment variable but I was thinking of a solution that works out of the box, or an ,as much as possible, automated procedure. The OS should be windows 7, but ideally should work on any version. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Are you limited to any kind of OS? For example linux only?

Comment: What if create symlinks to portable folders?

Comment: Instead of making you development environment portable, make you android project source code portable. It is better not to bind you project source to any IDE and OS, check out the samples downloaded from SDK manager as a good example.

Comment: I dont think symlinks would work...I am not sure I understand what you have in mind, but the whole env could be in a usb stick, thus changind driver letter and the .android folder is always created under C:\Users\<current_user>

Comment: The thought is more like when a new developer joins the team everything will be ready, with a one click installer, to code in Android!

Comment: Great idea to include the JDK and set the relative path in the eclipse.ini file!

Comment: @ThomasKaliakos, Is the Android SDK folder itself portable?

Comment: @Pacerier Yes, the Android SDK folder is portable. AFAIK the only thing that you need in general after copying/installing it, is adding the platform-tools folder in Path environment variable. In that way you can run for example adb from command line from any folder.

Comment: @ThomasKaliakos, Weird... shouldn't the scripts within the tools folder be dependent on platform?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think I found a way to do this on a Mac and Windows.  I have tested both solutions on multiple computers, but not exhaustively.

I had basically the same approach as you, but the problem is that the relative path for the Android SDK in Eclipse breaks the AVD Manager for some reason. It wouldn't allow me to run existing or create new AVDs. I got around this by including an "initial_setup" script that is to be run one time to set the Android SDK based on where the user unzips this package. It also creates the initial AVD for them. So they download and unzip the package, run the initial_setup script, and are good to go with a default Android development environment.

**The key is updating Eclipse ADT Plugin preferences to use the absolute path of the Android SDK.** This is accomplished with this line from the script below. Note that the path for the preferences file is relative to the workspace (and the workspace path is set as relative to the Eclipse installation).

```
echo com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.sdk=$sdk_path >> ./workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.prefs
```

**Mac Instructions**

Here's my unzipped directory structure:

```
android_dev_environment (root)
  - android-sdk-macosx
  - eclipse
  - initial_setup
  - workspace
```

And here are the contents of initial_setup:

```
#!/bin/bash 
# Set the Android SDK path in Eclipse. Must be the absolute; a relative path
# does not work with the AVD Manager.
cd "$(dirname "$0")"
sdk_path=`pwd`/android-sdk-macosx
echo "Setting Android SDK path in Eclipse..."
echo com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.sdk=$sdk_path >> ./workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.prefs
echo "Android SDK path set."

# Create a new AVD
echo "Creating new AVD..."
echo no | $sdk_path/tools/android create avd -n Android403 -t 1 --force
echo "AVD created."
```

**Windows Instructions**

Here's my unzipped directory structure:

```
android_dev_environment (root)
  - android-sdk-windows
  - eclipse
  - initial_setup.bat
  - java
  - workspace
```

The Windows version has its own local JDK 6 in the java directory.  Eclipse needs to know about it, so edit eclipse\eclipse.ini. Add the following lines [above the -vmargs line](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#Specifying_the_JVM):

```
-vm 
..\Java\jdk1.6.0_33\bin\javaw.exe
```

And here are the contents of initial_setup.bat:

```
REM Set the Android SDK path in Eclipse. Must be the absolute; a relative path
REM does not work with the AVD Manager.
cd > temp.txt 2>&1
set /p sdk_path= < temp.txt
del temp.txt
set sdk_path=%sdk_path%\android-sdk-windows
set sdk_path=%sdk_path:\=\\%
set sdk_path=%sdk_path::=\:%

echo “Setting Android SDK path in Eclipse...”
echo com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.sdk=%sdk_path%>> .\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime\.settings\com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.prefs
echo “Android SDK path set.”

REM Create a new AVD
echo “Creating a new AVD...”
echo no | .\android-sdk-windows\tools\android create avd -n Android403 -t 1 --force
echo “AVD created.”

pause
```

**For 64 bit Windows** you also need to tweak the find_java.bat file in the Android SDK so that it finds the Java installed with the bundle.  Add the following lines to android-sdk-windows\tools\lib\find_java.bat (before it runs its own check that starts with the comment "rem Check we have a valid Java.exe..."

```
set java_exe=%~dp0\..\..\..\Java\jdk1.6.0_33\bin\java.exe
set javaw_exe=%~dp0\..\..\..\Java\jdk1.6.0_33\bin\javaw.exe
if defined javaw_exe goto :EOF
```

**How to Use the Environment Bundle**

1. Unzip the bundle
2. Double-click on initial_setup in the android_dev_environment folder to set the Android SDK path to the user’s absolute path and create the default AVD
3. Run the Eclipse executable inside the eclipse directory

**Note:** Running initial_setup on a Mac or a PC multiple times does not hurt anything. The dev environment will break if the user moves the whole directory after initial_setup, but running initial_setup from the new location will fix it.  I plan on including a README file with these instructions.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Although right now I don't have the time to test this thoroughly, it is a really nice approach, so I will accept your answer. Thank you very much.

Comment: I tried using this file structure on my Mac but when I run the script it keeps saying that the directory doesn't exist. How do I go about doing this manually?

Comment: I manually created the android_dev_environment directory, unzipped android-sdk-macosx, unzipped eclipse, and manually created the workspace directory.  With all those in place the initial_setup script should work.  I'm writing a blog post about how to set this up manually and will post that in here when it's up.

Comment: This is kind of unnecessary with Google's own ADT bundle now, but for what it's worth, here's my blog post about this process: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/the-one-stop-android-sdk-installer-you-always-wanted

Answer (score 2):

If your willing to use linux you could use a portable operating system on your flash drive with all your settings and programs exactly how you like them on any computer with a usb drive. Or use a live cd and save to another location. I dont know how you could do it with windows

Answer (score 0):

While the above "approved" answer has a lot of great information, information that has helped me!, I'd like to point out another answer that has a different - more literal - take on the word "portable."

Check out [Terminal-IDE](http://Terminal-IDE.com/) for Android phones!

Terminal-IDE provides an integrated development environment (IDE) that LITERALLY runs on a NON-ROOTED Android phone!

It ALSO provides your phone with SSH capabilities both outbound and INBOUND! So, you can literally log in to your phone from other computers! WAY COOL.

Frankly, I think Terminal-IDE is a FANTASTIC contribution to the Android environment.

Answer (score 0):

Above answer works fine.

If you are looking forward to use your Android Tablet as Android Development Tool, take a look at "AIDE - Android IDE - Java, C++". Here's [a link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aide.ui)! which is really a good option, I am currently using it and writing code on the go. Also allows to export signed APK.

Answer (score -1):

I've created a portable package of the android sdk (complete with ant/jdk/jre), available here:

http://staticchaos.freeoda.com/android/sdk/

You are on your own for the IDE however.